# What is the difference between $(command) and "$(command)"?

Tags: bash, shell

Most of the time I see `$(command)` used, but I have also seen `"$(command)"` for example:

```
if [ "$(command)" ]; then
    stuff
fi
```

What is the purpose of the quotes in the second example?

Comment: @Jesse_b that’s what I’m looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes tell the shell to consider the output of `command` as a whole. Without them, the script will be broken if the command's output happens to contain whitespaces or any of the special characters `\` `[` `*` `?`.